# VBA define Row Height - Optimization

Tags: excel, vba

I´ve created the code below which defines the height of a range of rows while checking if they are empty or not.

It is working as intended, however it´s surprisingly slow. For context the variable `length` has 64 rows and it´s taking approximately 15s to run.

Does anyone know how I could optimize this code?

Thanks

```
sub linhasdim()

' define a altura das linhas da folha planner

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

Sheets(1).Activate ' activa a sheet(1)

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row ' guarda o indice da ultima linha com conteudo da coluna O. Mesmo havendo vazios identifca a ultima linha

Length = Range(Range("O6"), Range("O" & Lastrow)).Rows.Count ' dimensão da coluna O ate a ultima celula com conteudo começando na O6

For i = 1 To Length ' loop na coluna O

    If Range("O6").Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" Then ' se célula O(i) não tem vazio altura = 20

     Range("O6").Offset(i, 0).RowHeight = 20

    Else ' se for vazio altura =3

    Range("O6").Offset(i, 0).RowHeight = 3

    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: So if "O7" is "" then its row height will be 20 else it will be 3? .. Does that O columns contains formulas? .. By "" , do you mean empty cells without formula?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply :). Nope it only has text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple and fast solution. Row height of the empty cells in the range is set to 20. Row height of the text/constant cells in the range is set to 3

```
Sub linhasdim()

' define a altura das linhas da folha planner

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

Sheets(1).Activate ' activa a sheet(1)

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row 
' guarda o indice da ultima linha com conteudo da coluna O. _
Mesmo havendo vazios identifca a ultima linha

Range(Range("O6"), Range("O" & Lastrow)). _
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.RowHeight = 20

Range(Range("O6"), Range("O" & Lastrow)). _
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).EntireRow.RowHeight = 3
' thought I wonder why row height the for cells with text is 3 !!
Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' better to reset the value

End Sub
```

Comment: HI thanks it worked great :D Just a followup question. On last line that you´ve added, why do you think it´s better to have it?

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`  is a application default. So, better to keep it that way, if there are more macros where you may need that. Same applies to ``Application.DisplayAlerts = True`` and ``Application.CutCopyMode = False``